# Volatility model combined with different distributions?

Tags: distributions, standard-deviation, fitting, volatility-forecasting

I am working on fitting distributions to financial data using different volatility models. The simplest case of a gaussian distribution I do understand:
The data is $\mathcal{N}$$(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distributed. So at each day I use a certain amount of data to estimate the $\mu$ and the $\sigma$. If I apply the "normal" ML I get as solution the empirical mean and empirical standard deviation. There I implement a volatility model, by not using the classical formula for the standard deviation and the full data set, but e.g. by using an exponentially weighted moving average. So I calculate a value for $\sigma$ with a model for each day and plug this into the formula of my normal distribution, ok. But what is in case of a more complicated distribution? E.g. the generalized hyperbolic distribution. How can I implement a volatility model? I mean, how can I combine it with the distribution? If I use classical ML approach, this does not use a volatility model, but in case of the generalized hyperbolic distribution, there is no $\sigma$ in the parameters, so I cannot just plug it in?

This master thesis http://www.math.chalmers.se/~palbin/mattiasviktor.pdf is doing it, but I do not understand how they do it? On page 48 they just say "Over a 1300 day period, the parameters of the probability density functions
are estimated every five days, using a 500 day window" And on page 50 they give the generalized hyperbolic distribution which uses e.g. a GARCH-AR volatility model?

The only way I can imagine is, that I calculate a value for $\sigma$ at each day, at for each day I match the moments of the distributions. But this is not ML? On page 84 you can see a nice picture, for each day the hyperbolical distribution is combined with a volatility model.

I am interested in doing this, since I want to calculate the VaR over a time period with fitting a distribution and using a time volatility model.

ok edit, so in more detail:
I have financial data (http://uploadeasy.net/upload/cdm3n.rar). These are the losses (negative returns) of, I think the last 10 years of a company.

I want to calculate the VaR using a distribution with a volatility model. So first of all, I assume a normal distribution: $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$.

The VaR is nothing else, than the quantile: $VaR_\alpha=F^{-1}(\alpha)$

So I have a volatility model for my $\sigma$, I get for each day a value, so $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,...,\sigma_n$. For simplicity reasons I set $\mu$ to zero. So I have for each day a normal distribution with mean zero and a sigma which comes from the volatility model. Lets use a very simple volatility model, e.g. the (empirical) standard deviation of the last 10 days. So I use the first 10 days the calculate the volatility for the 11th day and so on. I plug this into my normaldistribution to compute the quantile. The R code would be e.g.

```
volatility<-0
quantile<-0
for(i in 11:length(dat)){
volatility[i]<-sd(dat[(i-10):(i-1)])
}

for(i in 1:length(dat)){
quantile[i]<-qnorm(0.975,mean=0,sd=volatility[i])
}
# the first quantile value is the VaR for the 11th date

#plot the volatility
plot(c(1:length(volatility)),volatility,type="l")

#add VaR
lines(quantile,type="l",col="red")
```

How can I do this in case of a non standardized t distribution with $\nu,\mu,\beta$. Or in case of a generalized hyperbolic distribution?

Comment: You don't match moments, you just need to make sure to set up your Maximum Likelihood properly. In any case, there are plenty of packages that estimate Garch with non-normal errors (e.g. http://www.kevinsheppard.com/wiki/MFE_Toolbox)

Comment: @John thanks, but this doesn't help me. I mean, lets assume I have an exponentially weighted moving average, so I have an estimate for my $\sigma$. How do I now fit the distribution properly? If I have Gaussian, I can just plug in the $\sigma$, but in case of e.g. an hyperbolic distribution? I need this, since I want to afterwards calculate the quantile of the fitted distribution which uses the modelled volatility to compute the Value at Risk.

Comment: As I said, you just need to set up the Maximum Likelihood properly (though strictly speaking, you probably could take a GMM approach). Imagine you were fitting it with a t distribution, since that is more common. The conditional variance at each period would not be the same as the conditional $\sigma^{2}$ parameter for each period, but it is simple to make the adjustment so that you effectively back out the parameters given a choice of degrees of freedom.

Comment: @John thanks, but this is not detailed enough for me, I really need to know how to implement this. I edited my post, so you can see where I am stuck.